# Spark: Join two equally large dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to join two equally large dataframes. So a broadcast join is not an option. Cluster is crashing due to OOM.

`df_c = df_a.join(df_b, on=["category", "timestamp"])`

The join is done on a column "category", which has common values for large parts of the data and a column "timestamp" which has distinct values.

How can I improve the join?

My theory:
If the data is distributed to the workers in a way that each worker receives parts of both dataframes of the same category, each worker would only need to match the timestamps of its category. And shuffling data between the workers would not be necessary.

Is that possible in Spark? Or is that already happening automatically, by providing the column "category" to the join operation?

Comment: You can repartition on the join column just after reading the dataframe: . repartition("category")

Comment: But how would Spark know, which parts of both dataframes (same category) need to be placed on the same worker. Then the join would be a narrow transformation, because no shuffle would be needed. Is tehre a way of doing that? Or is Spark doing that already automatically?